# how do i create an array with the name passed on to it in a method arg (in java)

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string

I'm writing a personal program that will help my Dnd group and at the same time expand my java knowledge a little :) now part of that involves some arrays, and loading text into them from a text file. Now I have succeeded in that and with them all set statically it's all fine, since the end result will have lots of arrays I thought rather than making each array do all the leg work itself I would create an array handler method.

So I would do `filetest(filename,arrayName)` (ie `filetest(table1,table1Array)`
and it would make the array, but I'm stuck on one thing: How do I make the array using the name from `arrayName`?

It's pretty much got me stumped my so far failed code is:

```
public class arrayFileHandler {
public static void fileTest(String fileName,String arrayName) throws FileNotFoundException{
int a = 0;
    System.out.println("test");
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); //this is the folder where the file SHOULD be
Scanner testTable1 = new Scanner(new File("data/"+fileName+".txt")); //with luck this will load the file ! if i understand + correct!
//Scanner testTable1 = new Scanner(new File("C:/Dev/newjava/dnd/src/dnd/test.txt")); //this works but is no good for our needs
ArrayList<String> testTable = new ArrayList<String>(); //create the array list since at this stage we dont know how long the array will be

while(testTable1.hasNextLine()){ //see if the file we are using has a next line (could cause me issues if the txt has blank lines...hmmm)
    String line = testTable1.nextLine(); //put that line into the string "line"
    testTable.add(line); //add that line to the array list
    System.out.println(line); //lets see what that line says 
    a++; //to help count the lines(not needed now)
    speechHandler.speechSynth(2, 1, 0, 60, line); //a debug line
}
System.out.println("there are "+ a +" lines"); //print how many lines there are
String arrayName[] = new String [testTable.size()]; //create an array with the number of "slots" equal to the number of slots in the arraylist and named with the String in arrayName
arrayName = testTable.toArray(arrayName);//copy the arraylist to the array
System.out.println(arrayName[0]);
//System.out.println(tableList[2]);
speechHandler.speechSynth(2, 1, 0, 60, arrayName[2]); //also a debug line
}
```

Now the important line is `String arrayName[] = new String [testTable.size()];` it's trying to create an array called `arrayName`, but I need it to be created with whatever name is in the string called `arrayName`, so in my example in the second paragraph it would be called `table1Array`.

Googling hasn't helped me much and I'm wondering if what I want to do is actually possible.

Comment: I would highly suggest a beginners programming book, but the short answer is "That's now things work". What you're looking for is a `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: what you want to achieve by giving names at run-rime? You can give any name.

Comment: Why do you want to set an array name at run-time? It has no significance at all while running, it's purely so people seeing the source code can understand what it's for.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of comments. :)

Comment: basicly there will be a lot of arrays from a lot of text files, rather then writing the code out for each array i was hoping to use this to create the arrays as they are needed with 1 line, saving me a lot of extra typing (well ok i could cut and paste) and to see if it was possible to do so

Comment: @Zabri im quite old and forgetfull so as i learn i comment, it helps when i look back at the code later :)

Comment: @BrianRoach sadly the way my brain works is by doing so this is the best way for me to learn, i only ask for help when truely stuck, i will search for info on Map<string, List<String>> in a bit though any links to resources on it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible and it also doesn't make any sense in your case. What's your goal? You're just creating a local variable, it doesn't matter which name did you choose. It'd only get complicated, because you'd need to access it using another variable (containing the name). I really don't see any usage in this.

If you were using some dynamic interpreted language, it could be done by using something like "eval", which would create variable with defined name at runtime. But in the Java, all code (including all variables etc) is compiled into bytecode and then executed. Do you see the problem? At compile time, the variable might not be recognized (because of missing name), and therefore it's not possible. Truth is, that bytecode doesn't contain local variable's names, but why JVM would have to solve issues like "isn't there already a variable with such a name" and so on? Bytecode would only get bigger, without actually bringing some new functionality.

If you really need this for some reason (and I just can't imagine which is that), I'd suggest you to use some sort of associative array, e.g. java.lang.Hashtable<>. It allows you to change names runtime.

Comment: I see, ok that does answer it, as i say it was to make life easier while programming so i only needed handler to set up all the arrays i needed as i needed them but since thats not possible i will just make a seperate handler per array and cut and paste it, not a big deal atleast i now know of this limitation.

Comment: You don't need to copy & paste your code. Just use that Hashtable, which will allow you to save multiple pairs key:value. In your case, key is something like variable name.

Answer (score 0):

From you last comment, if I understand right, you want to create arrays of strings based on the contents of text files.

You started with reading the lines into an ArrayList of Strings. I suggest you stick with ArrayLists, and not bother with arrays.

If you are going to read lots of files, I suggest you put your code which creates the ArrayLists into a method so you can call it as many times as you want, once for each file.
Below is such a function, copied from your code and modified where necessary (I removed the comments):

Here goes:

```
public List<String> getLinesFromFile(String filename) {

  Scanner testTable1 = new Scanner(new File(filename));
  List<String> testTable = new ArrayList<String>(); 

  while(testTable1.hasNextLine()){ 
    String line = testTable1.nextLine();
    testTable.add(line); 
  }

  return testTable;
}
```

You can call that as many times as you like. If you have lots of files, you can 'name' them the same as your filename by storing them in a Map:

First, create a Map whose keys are Strings (so we can look up by filename) and whose values are List (lists of strings - the content of the files)

```
Map<String, List<String>> fileContentMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Next, every time we read a file, add it to the Map:

```
String filename = // ... whatever file to read next
fileContentMap.put(filename, getLinesFromFile(filename));
```

Finally, when you want to retrieve them:

```
//retrieve lines from a file I read earlier:
List<String> lines = fileContentMap.get(filename);
```

Comment: ah i understood array lists to be temp designed to be an intermediary  between your data and an actual array when you did not know the amount of data to be used (as arrays have to have the number of entries specified in advance)
thats why i was creating the list and then "converting" that list to an array, 
i will more then likely go the route of a seperate method for each table i need to make but use arrayList instead of arrays, that seems the sensible approach, thank you

Comment: Oh no, not sure were you got that idea. I suggest some good reading material would be about Java Collections in general. Not sure why you want a separate method for each table if they are all doing the same thing. Just call the same method many times.